# Background image is not being shown

Tags: css

I check my image directory. It is okay. My code is:

```
div.user-feedback {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 21px;
    font-style: italic;
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: red ;
    background-image: url('../img/certificatebg.png');
}
```

My target div turned into red but no background image is shown. What is the problem in my code? My directory is:
[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hgmvq.png)

My css is placed inside ecommerce.css

Comment: check console for errors. you will be able to point out the issue

Comment: Agreed with @Reddy. First step should always be to check what the console is telling you.

Comment: if the image is available it should be shown: https://jsfiddle.net/yrrw1pj2/

Comment: @Toby his div is visible as he says he can see the red color div... So I dont think width is an issue

Comment: Is this an MVC app by any chance? - if so it might be better to use the ~/ in place of ../

Comment: @WebDevelopWolf "~" can be used outside MVC too :)

Comment: Yes. I am using cakephp

Answer (score 0):

I think its probably to do with the path for your URL not being correct within the context of the site. Try doing url('/img/certificatebg.png') so you are alsways starting from the root.

Answer (score 0):

Just use background-color instead of just background